# ¿Como hacer que un api trabaje con BD local y remota?

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, api, localhost

Hola tengo una pregunta.

Estoy realizando un api en .net C# (BackEnd), MySql (XAMMP) y Angular (FrontEnd).

Tengo que validar que cuando se trabaja de manera local sin conexión a internet la información se guarde en el computador, pero cuando se vuelva a conectar todo lo que se ha trabajado suba automáticamente (o dándole a un botón, no importa la manera).

Tengo planeado que cada que se ejecute haga ping al server y si no responde empiece atrabajar de manera local, pero ¿como hago cuando si de ping? ¿como envio toda la información local del pc al servidor?